# Proving a function defines a distance in the space of random variables

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions

> Let $\{X_{n}\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of random variables.
>   Prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty} X_{n} = 0$ in probability if and only if
>   $\lim_{n\to\infty} E(|X_{n}|/(1 + |X_{n}|) = 0$. Also, show that
>   $\rho(X, Y) = \mathbb{E}|X - Y|/(1 + |X - Y|)$ defines a distance in
>   the space of equivalence classes of random variables.

I am specifically not so sure how to do the latter part in which I am to prove that $\rho(X, Y)$ defines a distance in the space of equivalence classes of random variables. I would really appreciate any help on this problem as I have not really seen any examples ever that are very similar to it.

The solution to the first part is here: [$X_n \to 0$ in probability iff $E\left( \frac{|X_n|}{1+|X_n|}\right) \to 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1931227/x-n-to-0-in-probability-iff-e-left-fracx-n1x-n-right-to-0?rq=1)

Thank you

Comment: Check that $\rho$ is a *pseudometric*, i.e., a function satisfying all the defining properties of a metric except for the non-degeneracy. Then check that $\rho(X,Y)=0$ if and only if $X=Y$ almost surely, hence if and only if $X$ and $Y$ lie in the same equivalence class.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: On $[0,\infty)$ the function $\frac x {1+x}$ is an increasing  and a simple algebraic argument shows that $\frac {x+y} {1+x+y} \leq \frac x {1+x}+\frac y {1+y}$. This gives triangle inequality. Symmetry of the metric is obvious. If $E\frac  {|X-Y|} {1+|X-Y|}=0$ then $X=Y$ almost surely. So $E\frac  {|X-Y|} {1+|X-Y|}$ defines a metric on the space  of random variables provided we consider $X$ and $Y$ as equal if $X=Y$ almost surely.

Details for  triangle inequality: let $f(x)=\frac x {1+x}, A=|X-Y|, B=|X-Z|$ and $C=|Z-Y|$. Then $A\leq B+C$. Since $f$ is increasing we get $f(A) \leq f(B+C)$. Since $f(x+y) \leq f(x)+f(y)$ we get $f(A) \leq f(B)+f(C)$. If you take expectation in this you get triangle inequality.

Comment: How does $(x + y)/(1 + x + y) \leq \frac{x}{1 + x} + \frac{y}{1 + y}$ give the triangle inequality? I don't quite see it

Comment: You have to start with $|X-Z| \leq |X-Y|+|Y-Z|$, use monotonicity of $\frac x {1+x}$ and then  use this inequality.  @ExKo

Comment: I am confused. we get $\frac{|X - Z|}{1 + |X - Z|} \leq \frac{|X - Y| + |Y - Z|}{1 + |X - Z|}$ from monotonicity, and then how do you go to $\frac{|X - Y|}{1 + |X - Y|} + \frac{|Y - Z|}{1 + |Y - Z|}$?

Comment: @ExKo Sorry for the delay in responding to you. I have added some details to my answer now.